# IIS slow down client request without Internet

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a server (windows server 2008 r2) which hosting an asp.net web application locally using IIS. I also have several client PCs connected to the network which allow client PCs to access the website locally by hostname or IP address (e.g. http:// server / or http:// 192.168.1.200 /)

My Internet connection is not stable, up and down (disconnect) quite frequent. Because of that I discovered that my web application access from client PCs is smooth (load time less than 5 secs per page) when my Internet connection is ON (connected), but on the other hand, when the Internet connection is down (disconnected), access to the web application from client PCs take around 15-17 secs to complete the page load, every pages.

I doubt that this is related to IIS itself or my configuration is wrong.

Is there anyone else having the same issue? Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.

I didn't know that System.net.dns.gethostentry require Internet to work properly. So I have disable this function for my system to run smoothly now.